# Django tutorial 1.7 ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Working through the Django 1.7 tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/. I am unable to get the `choice_set.all()` for a given question.

Here is the python `manage.py` shell command line:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 24 2014, 21:26:19)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from elections.models import Question, Choice
>>> q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> # Display any choices from the related object set.
>>> q.choice_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'choice_set'
```

My `models.py` has a relation from choice to question using a ForeignKey as per the tutorial:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I am using a sqlite3 database. Why does the `choice_set` has no attribute?

Comment: Your error does not correspond to the code you have shown. Make sure you clear all the pyc files once and try again

Comment: @karthikr I copied the wrong error at first. The correct error message is: AttributeError: 'Question' object having no attribute 'choice_set'. I removed all .pyc files and retested and received the same error

Comment: Are there any values in the DB and is the DB up to date after any model changes?

Comment: Can you try **question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="choices")** and access choices by **q.choices.all()**

Comment: I created project with your models, everything works fine. Try to reinstall enviroment and clean all `*.pyc`

Comment: @ArunGhosh here is the result of after trying q.choices.all() :    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: @coldmind what exactly does reinstalling the enviroment entail? removing python/django and reinstalling?

Comment: @user1535867 what does q.choices return?

Comment: If you are using virtualenv, then delete enviroment directory and recreate it. If not, try to reinstall django and clean all python compiled files.

Comment: @ArunGhosh q.choices returns:    []

Comment: @user1535867 does that question have any choices? if not added choice and check q.choices.

Comment: @user1535867 I try to add a choice with: q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not Much', votes=0) and get the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'choice_set'

Comment: WOW! I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had created the polls app, just with different names, ex) polls->elections, choice->candidate. When I created the foreign key, I assumed choice_set was the permanent name for the reverse link to choices. I was trying to use choice_set when I should have been using candidate_set. I ran through the tutorial 4x trying to solve the error, and I realize the problem would have been caught if I had submitted the correct code for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quit your python shell with quit() command, then open shell again, it should work now.